# Eclipse, SVN trouble

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

A have copied a folder from one project, which is generated by system to another. Now I want to commit all stuff from the project, the folder was copied to. 
What I get is (that copied folder is in folder /webapp):

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Attempted to lock an already-locked dir
svn: Working copy '/home/user/webshop/webshop-impl/src/main/webapp' locked

Ok, I tried to Team->Cleanup and got:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Path is not a working copy directory
svn: '/home/user/webshop/webshop-impl/src/main/webapp/gwtmodules' is not a working copy directory

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Path is not a working copy directory
svn: '/home/user/webshop/webshop-impl/src/main/webapp/gwtmodules' is not a working copy directory
```

This eclipse SVN client is messing with me long time with this darn tigris exceptions =)

Please, help with advice :) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the projects in the same repository?

Comment: If someone answered this correctly, please mark it as an answer, otherwise edit the question to explain in more detail why none of these wasn't the right answer.

Answer (score 24):

This had me baffled as well when I got this error. This happens if we have some pending sessions on committing our changes so we’ll need to do some clean up before we’ll have another try on a commit.

**This is the fix:**

In STS or eclipse, right click on the offending project, click Team and then select Refresh/Cleanup. SVN gets the offending .lock files and deletes them.  You can also do this from the command line.

Comment: For me there were no .lock files laying around (which usually caused me this or similar issues) and doing a Refresh/Cleanup did the trick.

Comment: Even when I click Refresh/Cleanup I still get that same error.

Comment: This approach solved my problem with the locks, thanks!

Comment: When I find something like this I try to post the answer.  I try to give back on SO, as it has been a life saver for me more than once!

Comment: It would be nice if someone got it!

Answer (score 3):

You should delete .svn folders which contains repo info after you copy a directory to another place.

You are probably seeing it because the copied directory has some svn file which points to some place that does not match to the new location.

Comment: I have checked this copied folder. There is now any svn information in it :(

Comment: Also these are hidden folders so you should turn on view hidden files and folders in your system settings if you can't see them

Comment: are you using windows. those files are normally hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an `svn export` from the first project. This will give you a clean copy of the code without any of the associated svn metadata. You can then add the exported code into the second repository.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your folder is lack of svn info(my case). To fix it, you can copy svn info from other folders, and then modify the snv file(all-wcpropc,entries) to the correct one.
I am not sure it is the recommended way, but it works for me!